# Unable to add make JTextArea show multiplie lines insidea JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make multiple lines of a JTextArea visible.I am using GridBagLayout to add the components. Here is a code snippet:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import java.awt.*;


public class SSCE {
    SSCE(){
        JFrame f1=new JFrame();
        GridBagLayout gbl=new GridBagLayout();
        JButton btnAddAcc=new JButton("Add Acount");
        JButton insertId=new JButton("Insert");
        JButton insertTweet=new JButton("Insert2");
        JButton tweetButton=new JButton("TweetButton");

        JLabel accountStatusHeader=new JLabel("account  status Header");
        JLabel accountDisplayNameHeader=new JLabel("account  displayname Header");
        JLabel enterInterval=new JLabel("enter Interval!!");

        final JTextArea accountDispName = new JTextArea(50, 50);
        final JTextArea statusDisplay = new JTextArea(50, 50);

        final JTextArea jTextAreaId = new JTextArea(20, 50);
        final JTextArea jTextAreaTweets = new JTextArea(20, 50);
        jTextAreaId.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED,
                Color.PINK, Color.GREEN));
        final JTextArea tweetLog = new JTextArea(100, 100);
        tweetLog.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 5000));
        JScrollPane tweetLogPaneScroll = new JScrollPane(tweetLog);
        JScrollPane idScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTextAreaId);
        JScrollPane tweetScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTextAreaTweets);


        final JTextField timeIntervalInput = new JTextField(20);
        final JTextField tagIdInsertTextBox = new JTextField(50);
        final JTextField tweetInsertTextBox = new JTextField(50);



        f1.setLayout(gbl);
        f1.add(btnAddAcc,makeGbc(0,0,1,2));
        f1.add(accountDisplayNameHeader,makeGbc(1,0));
        f1.add(accountStatusHeader,makeGbc(1,1));
        f1.add(accountDispName,makeGbc(2,0));
        f1.add(statusDisplay,makeGbc(2,1));
        f1.add(enterInterval,makeGbc(3,0));
        f1.add(timeIntervalInput,makeGbc(3,1));
        f1.add(new JLabel("Twitter Ids"),makeGbc(4,0));
        f1.add(new JLabel("Tweets"),makeGbc(4,1));
        f1.add(idScrollPane,makeGbc(5,0,5));
        f1.add(tweetScrollPane,makeGbc(5,1,5));
        f1.add(tagIdInsertTextBox,makeGbc(10,0));
        f1.add(tweetInsertTextBox,makeGbc(10,1));
        f1.add(insertId,makeGbc(11,0));
        f1.add(insertTweet,makeGbc(11,1));
        f1.add(tweetButton,makeGbc(12,0,1,2));
        f1.add(tweetLogPaneScroll,makeGbc(13,0,6,2));


        f1.setSize(800,400);
        f1.setVisible(true);
        f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        accountDispName.setVisible(false);
        statusDisplay.setVisible(false);

    }
    private GridBagConstraints makeGbc(int y, int x) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
//        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
//        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = y;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        gbc.anchor = (y == 0) ? GridBagConstraints.LINE_START : GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        return gbc;
    }
    private GridBagConstraints makeGbc(int y, int x,int gridheight) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
//        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = gridheight;
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = y;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        gbc.anchor = (y == 0) ? GridBagConstraints.LINE_START : GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        return gbc;
    }
    private GridBagConstraints makeGbc(int y, int x,int gridheight,int gridwidth) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = gridwidth;
        gbc.gridheight = gridheight;
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = y;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        gbc.anchor = (y == 0) ? GridBagConstraints.LINE_START : GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        return gbc;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                SSCE a1;
                a1 = new SSCE();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Please note the following lines:

```
f1.add(idScrollPane,makeGbc(5,0,5));
f1.add(tweetScrollPane,makeGbc(5,1,5));
```

In above, I am passing the third paramenter(the gridheight) as 5 but still I see only one row. I want to set the row span to 5.
And Also the following:

```
f1.add(tweetLogPaneScroll,makeGbc(13,0,6,2));
```

Here again, I am passing the third param(gridheight) as 6.But yet I see only one Row of textarea. So what is going wrong?? And whats the solution?

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing to me. Better would have been if you created and posted an [sscce](http://sscce.org). Is your problem that your JTextArea doesn't wrap words? If not, have you called `setLineWrap(true)` and `setWrapStyleWord(true)` on it? Also, you haven't called `setSize(...)` or `setPreferredSize(...)` on the JTextArea? If so, get rid of that code as this should not be used on JTextAreas.

Comment: Also, how are you adding "lines" to the JTextArea? Again, I fear that some of the lines of code you've removed `"for clarity and relevance"` may indeed have been relevant. I'm not asking to see all of your code, just the code that causes this problem. Again, an [sscce](http://sscc.org) would be your best bet for showing us this.

Comment: Please re-read my comments -- I recommend that you should **not** use `setSize(...)` or `setPreferredSize(...)` especially on the JTextArea as this will prevent the component from expanding as it should be able to do. And please do not post code on an outside site with a link that is likely to go stale soon. Again, please show the *pertinent* code here, again best as an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels see edited question.Hope that helps further..

Comment: You've posted code, but none of it relates to showing a JTextArea, which is your main problem. Again consider posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) (please click on link).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels now I hope the pasted code is what you call an SSCE. The ball is in your court !! :)

Comment: Your SSCCE solves everything. I've voted to open your question and have up-voted it. You're killing yourself with your unrealistic JTextArea row numbers, and then setting the size of your GUI. Get rid of all `setSize(...)` and `setPreferredSize(...)` method calls. Make your JTextArea row counts 5 or 10, not 50, not 100. Call `pack()` before `setVisible(true)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SSCCE helps me to see everything -- thanks! I've voted to open your question and have up-voted it. You're killing yourself with your unrealistic JTextArea row numbers, and then setting the size of your GUI. Get rid of all `setSize(...)` and `setPreferredSize(...)` method calls. Make your JTextArea row counts 5 or 10, not 50, not 100. Call `pack()` before `setVisible(true)`.

For example, please see the changes I've made below as well as comments with `!!` in them. Note that I've tried to get rid of *most* of your magic numbers, but you still need to do the same with the column counts. I've also added text to your text components for the sake of debugging, so that I can see at a glance which text component goes with which variable. You'll of course not want to have this text present in the presentation code, but again, it's a useful debugging tool:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import java.awt.*;

public class SSCE {
   private static final int SMALL_ROWS = 5; // !! was 20!
   private static final int BIG_ROWS = 10; // !! was 50!

   SSCE() {
      JFrame f1 = new JFrame();
      GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
      JButton btnAddAcc = new JButton("Add Acount");
      JButton insertId = new JButton("Insert");
      JButton insertTweet = new JButton("Insert2");
      JButton tweetButton = new JButton("TweetButton");
      JLabel accountStatusHeader = new JLabel("account  status Header");
      JLabel accountDisplayNameHeader = new JLabel(
            "account  displayname Header");
      JLabel enterInterval = new JLabel("enter Interval!!");
      final JTextArea accountDispName = new JTextArea("accountDispName JTA",
            BIG_ROWS, 50);
      final JTextArea statusDisplay = new JTextArea("statusDisplay JTA",
            BIG_ROWS, 50);
      final JTextArea jTextAreaId = new JTextArea("jTextAreaId JTA",
            SMALL_ROWS, 50);
      final JTextArea jTextAreaTweets = new JTextArea("jTextAreaTweets JTA",
            SMALL_ROWS, 50);
      jTextAreaId.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED,
            Color.PINK, Color.GREEN));
      final JTextArea tweetLog = new JTextArea("tweetLog JTA", BIG_ROWS, 100); // was
                                                                               // 100!
      // !! tweetLog.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 5000));
      JScrollPane tweetLogPaneScroll = new JScrollPane(tweetLog);
      JScrollPane idScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTextAreaId);
      JScrollPane tweetScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTextAreaTweets);
      final JTextField timeIntervalInput = new JTextField(
            "timeIntervalInput JTF", 20);
      final JTextField tagIdInsertTextBox = new JTextField(
            "tagIdInsertTextBox JTF", 50);
      final JTextField tweetInsertTextBox = new JTextField(
            "tweetInsertTextBox JTF", 50);
      f1.setLayout(gbl);
      f1.add(btnAddAcc, makeGbc(0, 0, 1, 2));
      f1.add(accountDisplayNameHeader, makeGbc(1, 0));
      f1.add(accountStatusHeader, makeGbc(1, 1));
      f1.add(accountDispName, makeGbc(2, 0));
      f1.add(statusDisplay, makeGbc(2, 1));
      f1.add(enterInterval, makeGbc(3, 0));
      f1.add(timeIntervalInput, makeGbc(3, 1));
      f1.add(new JLabel("Twitter Ids"), makeGbc(4, 0));
      f1.add(new JLabel("Tweets"), makeGbc(4, 1));
      f1.add(idScrollPane, makeGbc(5, 0, 5));
      f1.add(tweetScrollPane, makeGbc(5, 1, 5));
      f1.add(tagIdInsertTextBox, makeGbc(10, 0));
      f1.add(tweetInsertTextBox, makeGbc(10, 1));
      f1.add(insertId, makeGbc(11, 0));
      f1.add(insertTweet, makeGbc(11, 1));
      f1.add(tweetButton, makeGbc(12, 0, 1, 2));
      f1.add(tweetLogPaneScroll, makeGbc(13, 0, 6, 2));
      // !! f1.setSize(800, 400);
      f1.pack(); // !!
      f1.setVisible(true);
      f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      accountDispName.setVisible(false);
      statusDisplay.setVisible(false);
   }

   private GridBagConstraints makeGbc(int y, int x) {
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      // gbc.gridwidth = 1;
      // gbc.gridheight = 1;
      gbc.gridx = x;
      gbc.gridy = y;
      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      gbc.weighty = 1.0;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
      gbc.anchor = (y == 0) ? GridBagConstraints.LINE_START
            : GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      System.out.printf("gridwidth, gridheight: [%d, %d]%n", gbc.gridwidth,
            gbc.gridheight);
      return gbc;
   }

   private GridBagConstraints makeGbc(int y, int x, int gridheight) {
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      // gbc.gridwidth = 1;
      gbc.gridheight = gridheight;
      gbc.gridx = x;
      gbc.gridy = y;
      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      gbc.weighty = 1.0;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
      gbc.anchor = (y == 0) ? GridBagConstraints.LINE_START
            : GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      return gbc;
   }

   private GridBagConstraints makeGbc(int y, int x, int gridheight,
         int gridwidth) {
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridwidth = gridwidth;
      gbc.gridheight = gridheight;
      gbc.gridx = x;
      gbc.gridy = y;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
      gbc.anchor = (y == 0) ? GridBagConstraints.LINE_START
            : GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      return gbc;
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            SSCE a1;
            a1 = new SSCE();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

This results in a GUI that looks like so:

[image]

Note, I would also change the GridBagConstraints for JTextFields from BOTH to HORIZONTAL.

---

**Edit**
You state in comment:

> One more question if u dont mind answering.the TimeIntervalInput is appearing so wide although I have defined it to hold at max 20 chars.Any solution to that?

You need to continue to play with your grid bag constraints as the ones you're using are quite restrictive. For example, note what happens when I use more exacting constraints on the GBC for that JTextField:

```
  GridBagConstraints gbc = makeGbc(3, 1);
  gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
  gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
  f1.add(timeIntervalInput, gbc);
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. One more question if u dont mind answering.the TimeIntervalInput is appearing so wide although I have defined it to hold at max 20 chars.Any solution to that?

Comment: @rahulserver: you're welcome. It is a *very* useful tool as you can see.